# Input Value on another table only when necessary

Tags: excel, reference, lookup

I have another excel problem. What function do I need to display only a lead time when there is an order placed? For this example, the 3rd Lead Time RN "0.19" will be displayed on Week 7 of the first table. Can you please help me again. Thanks a lot.

My formula for the Lead Time column on the first table so far is:

=IF(I9=6,Q20,"")

But then again, I only want to display the next Lead Time RN on weeks in which an order is placed.

[Table 1 picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRz3K.png)
[image]

[image]
[Table 2 (Lead Time Table) picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAOtE.png)

[Whole Table 1 (Simulation Table)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wagPJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try this formula.

```
=IF($I9=6,VLOOKUP(COUNTIF($I$8:$I9,6),$P$20:$Q35,2,FALSE),"")
```

Here, P20:Q29 is the range of your lead time table. It could be on another sheet and I would make this a named range. "2" means that it's the value in the second column of the specified range. Column 1 must have the look-up list.

The lead time will only be looked up if I9 has a 6 in it. Else it will return "". However, I would recommend to return 0 instead and then format the cell to hide the zero if it isn't welcome. This is because 0 is a number which you can use in multiplications that might follow, producing a production time of 0. "" on the other hand, is a string of text and you will need to convert that to 0 in the formula that processes it, which isn't very elegant, seeing that the next formula is needed to correct the error of the first.

Comment: I tried your formula, but all lead times are 0.42 since the the lookup value is column I and everything there is "6". I think we're getting near.

Comment: I thought the value in column I was to specify the row in the lead time table. If it isn't, how and where do you specify the row?

Comment: Order Quantity is constant with "6". Thus, Column I just signifies whether an order has been placed on that week. Furthermore, Column P does not mean the week number but the order in which that specific lead time will be used. The next week that has an order placed is Week 7. It is the third time that a lead will be used. Thus, the third lead time (0.19) should be the lead time of Week 7. I hope I'm not that confusing. But thank you guys for all hour help

Comment: Is there any way to know from your table that the next time will be the 3rd time? What will be the lead time on the 11th time?

Comment: Hi, @Variatus. The only way to know from the main table that it will be the 3rd time is that an order has been placed (there is an order quantity of "6" on that specific week). There are actually 20 weeks and when I manually input the orders, there are only 8 weeks in which an order must been placed. Thus, only 8 lead times will be used of the 10 given. 

NOTE: The 20 Demand RNs and 10 Lead Time RNs are given from the problem.

Thanks and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Please try the revised formula.

Comment: It started on the 4th lead time (0.34) when I entered this formula on I9: =IF($I9=6,VLOOKUP(COUNTIF($I$9:$I18,6),$P$20:$Q35,2,FALSE),"") I edited the post and added another picture, which shows the whole simulation table (complete with 20 weeks) so that you could picture the whole thing going on with the simulation. I really do think we're getting very near.

Comment: COUNTIF($I$9:$I18,6) is wrong. You need the range from above the row of the formula to the row of the formula. In row 9 that is `COUNTIF($I$8:$I9,6)` as shown in my answer. As the formula is copied down it will become `($I$8:$I10`, `($I$8:$I11`, `($I$8:$I12` etc. - always counting the number of sizes in the range above and including the row of the formula.

Comment: Oh my goodness! You're my hero!!!! It already worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you for the accolade! I've modified the formula to match my last comment and indeed the text of my answer (using row 9). Since it solved your problem, please do mark it as *Selected*. Thank you.

Comment: Done! Selected yours as the answer to my question. You may also check out my other question. It's about inventory simulation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try : IF($I9>0,XLOOKUP($B9,$P$20:$P$29,$Q$20:$Q$29,"NO MATCH"),"")

Edit based on comment:

Try : IF($I$9>0,XLOOKUP(COUNTIF($I$9:$I$18,">0")-COUNTIF($I9:$I$18,">0")+1,$P$20:$P$29,$Q$20:$Q$29,"NO MATCH"),"")

Comment: I'm sorry but the Lead Time table might be confusing. Column P does not mean the week number but the order in which that specific lead time will be used. The next week that has an order placed is Week 7. It is the third time that a lead will be used. Thus, the third lead time (0.19) should be the lead time of Week 7. I hope I'm not that confusing. But thank you guys for all hour help

Comment: Thanks for the new function. I'll try later after work.

Comment: Did you try my formula, as you said you would?

Comment: I made a few tweaks to reflect to the whole worksheet. It also worked:

=IF($I9>0,XLOOKUP(COUNTIF($I$9:$I$28,">0")-COUNTIF($I9:$I$28,">0")+1,$P$20:$P$29,$Q$20:$Q$29,"NO MATCH"),"")

Comment: Ok. Since my answer worked and was submitted hours before the answer you selected, could you at least give me an upvote? It would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My reputation is still low so the score on the post cannot be displayed yet, but the site says it's recorded.